# Orchard command line says module is disabled even though it is enabled - cannot disable through UI

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.8

Disabling modules usually isn't a problem in Orchard... something is up with my install, though, and I need to know how to fix it.

I have an Orchard website hosted in a Microsoft Azure Website and with an SQL Compact DB. When I try to disable Shape Tracing from the UI, everything works as it usually does, except once the page has refreshed, Shape Tracing is still enabled.

There are no errors in the logs.

Further, Shape Tracing is disabled locally but not remotely. So I pushed the local .sdf file using FileZilla FTP. Shape tracing is still disabled remotely.

Also, I have tried restarting the website in the Azure Website portal. No dice. I am still unable to disable Shape Tracing.

I used https://mywebsite.scm.azurewebsites.net/DebugConsole to run `feature disable Orchard.DesignerTools`, and in the Orchard Admin UI shape tracing is still enabled and it is working to inspect shapes, even though the command line appeared to disable it, and `feature list /Summary:true` also lists DesignerTools as disabled.

Why does the Orchard command line indicate that Shape Tracing is disabled when Shape Tracing is clearly working? Further, why cannot I disable Shape Tracing from the Orchard Admin UI?

Hmm.

Comment: I just went into an Orchard fresh install of the newest release and disabled shape tracing with no issues. What version of Orchard are you running? --- Just noticed the tag saying 1.8
Is it possible for you to install a fresh copy of Orchard and see if it has the same issue for you?

Comment: I would really rather not install a fresh copy of Orchard... it might come to that, though, and wouldn't be the end of the world. Determining the root cause while nice can be a rabbit hole.

Comment: When it comes to orchard, you have to appreciate how quick and easy it is to rebuild a website from scratch with access to the db and files :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shaun it looks like going into the database and manually disabling the shape tracing feature is going to be the best solution to your problem on this one. Even on the Orchard forums themselves this is the solution to a users problem having the same issues.

https://orchard.codeplex.com/discussions/443373

"You can disable the feature directly from the database. Look for Settings_ShellFeatureStateRecord table and set the EnableState for the ShapeTracing feature to Down. Be sure to delete the cache.dat file in App_Data and recycle the app pool (touching web.config will cause an app pool recycle)." -- sfmskywalker

Doing a fresh install and transitioning your data over to a new install is the other way i would go about fixing this.

Comment: I was having this issue (Orchard v.1.10.1.0) and the feature was disabled as soon as I deleted the App_Data/cache.data file and recycled the app pool (I didn't have to do anything in the database). It's possible that all you need to do is recycle the app pool, but deleting cache.dat seemed like a safe bet.